# Feynman diagrams - swapped only by vertex label

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, feynman-diagrams, wick-theorem

Consider as an **example** $\phi^3$ theory, which contains at second order both the contractions:
$$\newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle} \mean{\hat a_q \phi(\color{red}{x})}\mean{T\phi(x)\phi(x)}\mean{T\phi(y)\phi(y)}\mean{\phi(\color{red}{y})\hat a_p^\dagger}\tag1$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$ \mean{\hat a_q \phi(\color{red}{y})}\mean{T\phi(x)\phi(x)}\mean{T\phi(y)\phi(y)}\mean{\phi(\color{red}{x})\hat a_p^\dagger}\tag2$$
(Important difference indicated in red).
My question is: is it the *convention* to take these as separate diagrams or as the same (adjusting the symmetry factor accordingly)?

Comment: If anyone knows how to do the Wick's contraction symbols in mathjax please could you let me know - I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: In your case, it would be acceptable to use LaTeX and CTAN simplewick, or [Simple-Wick](https://jpellis.me/projects/simpler-wick/), to produce a PNG and include it in your question.

Comment: what are $a_q$ and $a_p^\dagger$?

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis They are by definition annihilation and creation operators of a particle into a state $\vec q$ and $\vec p$ respectively.

Comment: What is then their relation to the field $\phi$? If $a_k$ and $\phi$ are independent, then $\langle a_k \phi \rangle = 0 = \langle a_k^\dagger \phi \rangle$. So, your question is not still clear enough to answer. Please provide your action.

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis The standard relation - $a_k$ and $a_k^\dagger$ are the Fourier coefficients in the expansion of $\phi$. For a simple field theory like this I have never seen them defined any other way - AccidentalFourierTransform seemed to understand it correct.

Comment: I am not sure if it is standard; could you provide a reference?

Comment: @PhilosophiaeNaturalis pg11 of http://theory.fi.infn.it/casalbuoni/lezioni99.pdf